# "Column check constraint cannot reference other columns"

Tags: oracle

I get the error "Column check constraint cannot reference other columns" with the table below. How can I solve this?

```
CREATE TABLE SALES_ORDER
(
   S_ORDER_NO   VARCHAR2(6) PRIMARY KEY CHECK (S_ORDER_NO LIKE 'O'),
   S_ORDER_DATE DATE,
   DELY_ADDR    VARCHAR2(25),
   SALESMAN_NO  VARCHAR2(6) REFERENCES SALESMAN_MASTER(SALESMAN_NO),
   DELY_TYPE    CHAT(1) DEFAULT 'F' CHECK (DELY_TYPE IN ('P', 'F')),
   BILLED_YN    CHAT(1),
   DELY_DATE    DATE CHECK (DELY_DATE > S_ORDER_DATE),
   ORDER_STATUS VARCHAR2(10) CHECK (ORDER_STATUS IN ('PROCESS', 'FULFILLED', 'BLOCKORDER', 'CANCELED'))
);
```

Comment: `CHECK (DELY_DATE > S_ORDER_DATE)` needs to be at the table level. Not inline next to a column. Also `LIKE 'O'` is incorrect. Probably you wanted `LIKE 'O%'`

Comment: Error message is  Oracle

Comment: Just to elaborate on Martins comment. Remove the constraint from the table and add it outside like: `ALTER TABLE SALES_ORDER ADD CONSTRAINT <CNAME> CHECK (DELY_DATE > S_ORDER_DATE);`

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is not correct for row level CHECK constraints.

> `CHECK (DELY_DATE > S_ORDER_DATE)` needs to be at the table level.
>
> -- from Martin Smith's comments

Within the `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE SALES_ORDER
(
   S_ORDER_NO   VARCHAR2(6) PRIMARY KEY CHECK (S_ORDER_NO LIKE 'O'),
   S_ORDER_DATE DATE,
   DELY_ADDR    VARCHAR2(25),
   SALESMAN_NO  VARCHAR2(6) REFERENCES SALESMAN_MASTER(SALESMAN_NO),
   DELY_TYPE    CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'F' CHECK (DELY_TYPE IN ('P', 'F')),
   BILLED_YN    CHAR(1),
   DELY_DATE    DATE,
   ORDER_STATUS VARCHAR2(10) CHECK (ORDER_STATUS IN ('PROCESS', 'FULFILLED', 'BLOCKORDER', 'CANCELED')),
   constraint <CNAME> CHECK (DELY_DATE > S_ORDER_DATE)
);
```

Outside of the `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE SALES_ORDER
(
   S_ORDER_NO   VARCHAR2(6) PRIMARY KEY CHECK (S_ORDER_NO LIKE 'O'),
   S_ORDER_DATE DATE,
   DELY_ADDR    VARCHAR2(25),
   SALESMAN_NO  VARCHAR2(6) REFERENCES SALESMAN_MASTER(SALESMAN_NO),
   DELY_TYPE    CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'F' CHECK (DELY_TYPE IN ('P', 'F')),
   BILLED_YN    CHAR(1),
   DELY_DATE    DATE,
   ORDER_STATUS VARCHAR2(10) CHECK (ORDER_STATUS IN ('PROCESS', 'FULFILLED', 'BLOCKORDER', 'CANCELED'))
);


-- from Lennart's comments
ALTER TABLE SALES_ORDER ADD CONSTRAINT <CNAME> CHECK (DELY_DATE > S_ORDER_DATE);
```